# Parse multiple array similarity query

Tags: algorithm, search, parse-platform

I am working on an algorithm that will compare 2 objects, object 1 and object 2. Each object has attributes which are 5 different arrays, array A, B, C, D, and E.

In order for the two objects to be a match, at least one item from Object 1 A must be in Object 2 A AND Object 1 B must be in Object 2 B, etc through object E must be similar. With a higher number of matches in each array A-E, the higher of a score The match will produce.

Am I going to have to pull Object 1 and object 2 then do an n^2 complexity search on each array to determine which ones exist in both  arrays? Then I would go about serving a score by how many matches there were in each array, then add them up and the total would give me the score.

I feel like there has to be a better option for this, especially for Parse.com

Maybe I am going about this problem all wrong, can someone PLEASE help me with this problem. I would provide some code for this one, but I have not started the code yet because I cannot wrap my head around the best way to design it. The two object database are in place already though.
Thanks!

As I said, I may be thinking of this problem in the wrong way. If I am unclear about anything that I am trying to do, let me know and I will update accordingly.

Comment: I think that either way you're going to end up with N^2 complexity... checking everything in an array against everything in another array is just a sad time for people who like to make efficient algorithms. BUT if anyone has another solution, I'd be very excited to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

Copy all elements from some array object1 to hash table (unordered map), and thereafter iterate array in the 2nd object, and lookup presence in the map. Thus, time complexity is O(N).

Smart solution:

Keep elements in all objects not in the "naive arrays", but in the arrays, structured as hash tables with double hashing algorithm. If so, all arrays in an objects1, 2, already will be pre-indexed, and what is you needed - iterate array, contains less number of elements, and match elements vs longest pre-indexed array.